# Galaxy Tab 7" - can I install the original Android? any version would do

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, stock-android, google-calendar

I can't stand Samgsung's bloated customization of Android. It's slow and horrible.

Is there a way to get a custom rom for it? It doesn't have to be honeycomb or icecream sandwich. All I want is the original android system and basic google applications.

Particularly the Calendar and Contacts app are painful to look at. I would like to replace those with the originals, made by Google.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Which exact model of the Tab do you have?  There are at least 5 different models in the USA: two GSM-based (AT&T SGH-I987 and T-Mobile SGH-T849), two CDMA-based (Sprint SPH-P100 and Verizon/US Cellular SCH-I800) and the WiFi-only model (GT-P1010.) There are some other international models as well.  Each model is slightly different hardware-wise, so the custom ROMs are usually not interchangeable across them.

Comment: I have GT-P1000, bought in the UK without a carrier. It's WiFi and GSM.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Galaxy Tab roms on the XDA forums, [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=807), most of them with instructions on how to do it.